# What code is generated for an equals/hashCode method of a case class?

Tags: java, class, scala, equals, hashcode

I have some Java code which I'm translating to Scala.

The code consists of some immutable classes which would fit the purpose of a `case class` in Scala.

But I don't want to introduce bugs, therefore I want to be sure that the code being generated for `equals` and `hashCode` is/behaves equivalent to the current implementation.

I already looked in "Programming in Scala" but it only says

> Third, the compiler adds “natural” implementations of methods toString,
>   hashCode, and equals to your class.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Scala has a compiler option `-Xprint:typer`, which you can use to get the "post-typing source code that it uses internally".

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e 'case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)'
```

Here you see something like:

```
override def hashCode(): Int = ScalaRunTime.this._hashCode(Foo.this);
override def toString(): String = ScalaRunTime.this._toString(Foo.this);
override def equals(x$1: Any): Boolean = Foo.this.eq(x$1).||(x$1 match {
  case (a: String,b: Int)this.Foo((a$1 @ _), (b$1 @ _)) if a$1.==(a).&&(b$1.==(b)) => x$1.asInstanceOf[this.Foo].canEqual(Foo.this)
  case _ => false
});
```

But, this doesn't tell you how hashCode is generated.  Here's the source for that:

```
def _hashCode(x: Product): Int = {
  var code = x.productPrefix.hashCode()
  val arr =  x.productArity
  var i = 0
  while (i < arr) {
    val elem = x.productElement(i)
    code = code * 41 + (if (elem == null) 0 else elem.hashCode())
    i += 1
  }
  code
}
```

And, in this example, the first case of the equals pattern matching would just be:

```
case that: Foo => this.a == that.a && this.b == that.b
```

Comment: This shows how useful the Product trait is. The compiler doesn't have to generate a custom hashCode (or toString) for every case class. Instead, it can iterate over the "elements" of the object in a very generic fashion. That is, it combines the benefits of storing state in an object and storing it in a Map. i.e., generic operations over the collection. Clojure's defrecord form provides similar benefits.

Comment: Interesting.  That means that if a case class has primitive members, they're going to have to be boxed whenever hashCode is called.

Comment: As of scala 2.9, the hashCode generated for case classes uses MurmurHash.