# hashCode in case classes in Scala

Tags: scala, hashcode, case-class

I've read that Scala'a `case class` construct automatically generates a fitting `equals` and `hashCode` implementation. What does exactly the generated code look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What code is generated for an equals/hashCode method of a case class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526706/what-code-is-generated-for-an-equals-hashcode-method-of-a-case-class)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As my professor used to say, only the code tells the truth! So just take a look at the code that is generated for:

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)
```

We can instruct the Scala compiler to show us the generated code after the different phases, here after the typechecker:

```
% scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: test.scala
package <empty> {
  @serializable case class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject with Product {
    ..
    override def hashCode(): Int = ScalaRunTime.this._hashCode(A.this);
    ...
    override def equals(x$1: Any): Boolean = A.this.eq(x$1).||(x$1 match {
      case (i: Int,s: String)A((i$1 @ _), (s$1 @ _)) if i$1.==(i).&&(s$1.==(s)) => x$1.asInstanceOf[A].canEqual(A.this)
      case _ => false
    });


    override def canEqual(x$1: Any): Boolean = x$1.$isInstanceOf[A]()
  };
}
```

So you can see that the calculation of the hash code is delegated to [ScalaRunTime._hashCode](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/branches/2.8.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L151) and the equality depends on the equality of the case class' members.

Comment: This not only explains it well, but taught me about `-Xprint:typer`. Thanks a lot! The only thing I'm confused about is what does `ScalaRunTime.this` mean? Why not simply `ScalaRunTime._hashCode`?

Comment: The `ClassName.this` syntax is usually used to access an outer `this` from within an inner class (that's the same as in Java). Not sure why it's printed here, maybe it's just the way the code is pretty printed by the compiler. But that's just a guess, anyone else?

Answer (score 60):

The generated `hashCode`  just calls `scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode`, which is defined as:

```
def _hashCode(x: Product): Int = {
  val arr =  x.productArity
  var code = arr
  var i = 0
  while (i < arr) {
    val elem = x.productElement(i)
    code = code * 41 + (if (elem == null) 0 else elem.hashCode())
    i += 1
  }
  code
}
```

So what you get is `elem1 * 41**n + elem2 * 41**(n-1) .. elemn * 1`, where `n` is the arity of your case class and `elemi` are the members of that case class.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Now I don't know whether I should accept your answer or Mirko's answer, from which I also learnt the handy `-Xprint:typer` trick...

Comment: Together, both answers are perfectly answering the question :-)

Answer (score 19):

**Please be aware that the previous answers on this question are a bit outdated on the hashCode part.**

As of scala 2.9 `hashCode` for case classes uses `MurmurHash`: [link](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/branches/2.9.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L177).

MurmurHash [produces good avalanche effect, good distribution and is CPU friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899616/murmurhash-what-is-it).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like things have changed; using Mirko's example `case class A(i: Int, s: String)`I get:

```
override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = {
      <synthetic> var acc: Int = -889275714;
      acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, i);
      acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(s));
      scala.runtime.Statics.finalizeHash(acc, 2)
    };
```

and

```
override <synthetic> def equals(x$1: Any): Boolean = A.this.eq(x$1.asInstanceOf[Object]).||(x$1 match {
  case (_: A) => true
  case _ => false
}.&&({
      <synthetic> val A$1: A = x$1.asInstanceOf[A];
      A.this.i.==(A$1.i).&&(A.this.s.==(A$1.s)).&&(A$1.canEqual(A.this))
    }))
  };
```

Comment: It looks to me like `scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._hashCode` still works, though, and based on the comments in the code, I'd expect it to produce the same result.



ScalaRuntime delegates to MurmerHash3, which contains the comment: "Case objects have the hashCode inlined directly into the synthetic hashCode method, but this method should still give a correct result if passed a case object."