# Does Scala tuple type uses all of its elements to compute its hash code?

Tags: scala

Or does Scala compute tuple hashcode using something independent of its elements, like memory address?

In other words, given two `Tuple2`s `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, does `a == c && b == d` imply `(a, b).hashCode == (c, d).hashCode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does `a == c` && `b == d` imply `(a, b).hashCode == (c, d).hashCode`?

Yes, it does. This is the contract between `==` and `hashCode`. (*)

> Does Scala tuple type uses all of its elements to compute its hash code?

Yes, it does. Scala `Tuple2` is just a case class:

```
final case class Tuple2[@specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T1, @specialized(Int, Long, Double, Char, Boolean/*, AnyRef*/) +T2](_1: T1, _2: T2)
  extends Product2[T1, T2]
{
 ...
}
```

In Scala `hashCode` for a case class is calculated in the following way:

[hashCode in case classes in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866720/hashcode-in-case-classes-in-scala)

[What code is generated for an equals/hashCode method of a case class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526706/what-code-is-generated-for-an-equals-hashcode-method-of-a-case-class)

---

(*) From the following it can be seen that for case classes (including tuples) the contract is fulfilled.

Comment: So comparing `Map[(A, B), C]` with `Map[A, Map[B, C]]`, which one is better in term of querying performance?

Comment: *This is the contract between == and hashCode* Although that is the *requirement* (in general) from overriding `hashCode` and `equals`, there is no guarantee this will exist in reality, so you better verify. Perhaps it's worth mentioning in the answer.

Comment: @Will That really depends on the usecase. If you're looking up values by key, like you should when working with a `Map`, performance differences between the two should be negligible IMO as long as `A` has a "good" implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`, which is up to you to guarantee.  Also, you might need to take into account that you'll need to look up the additional `Map` which serves as the value of `A`, which might add to the total time. All in all, use JMH to micro benchmark.

Comment: @Will in such formulation the question is pointless. `Map` is just a trait, every its implementation can have its own behavior. Probable you asked about `HashMap`. Refer @Yuval's comment.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks, slightly updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Scala tuples (and case classes for that matter) implement `hashCode` and `==` based on all of their contents and nothing else.

So yes, `a == c && b == d` implies `(a, b).hashCode == (c, d).hashCode`, assuming the `hashCode` methods for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are also well-behaved.

Comment: So comparing Map[(A, B), C] with Map[A, Map[B, C]], which one is better in term of querying performance?

Comment: I suppose `Map[A, Map[B, C]]` will be a bit faster to look things up, especially if `B` has a slow hashCode method.