# How to implement equals and hashCode proper in scala

Tags: scala

Anyone tell me about the implementation of **equals** and **hashCode** methods in my code is proper or wrong. Does there need to implement **hashCode** and **equals** in case classes (**Product** and **Category**) or not?

```scala
trait BaseId {
  val value: Option[Long]
}

trait BaseEntity[T <: BaseId] {
  val id: T

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: BaseEntity[T] => (that canEqual this) && (that.id.value -> this.id.value match {
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) if x == y => true
      case _ => false
    })
    case _ => false
  }

  def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean = other.isInstanceOf[BaseEntity[T]]

  override def hashCode(): Int = id.value match {
    case Some(x) => x.##
    case None => super.hashCode()
  }
}

case class CategoryId(value: Option[Long]) extends BaseId

case class Category(id: CategoryId, name: String, products: Option[Seq[Product]]) extends BaseEntity[CategoryId]

case class ProductId(value: Option[Long]) extends BaseId

case class Product(id: ProductId, name: String, category: Category) extends BaseEntity[ProductId]
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to implement your own `equals` and `hashCode` methods for a `case class`.  These are provided to you by virtue of it being a `case class`, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312937/4126391).  Note that this is specific to `case class` only, not a regular plain old `class`.  You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526706/what-code-is-generated-for-an-equals-hashcode-method-of-a-case-class) for specific details on how those methods are implemented on a `case class`.

Comment: So, when I test with some code, it always yields true.

Comment: <!-- language: scala -->