# How `set.contains` works in Scala?

Tags: scala, set, equals, hashcode, case-class

Consider the following code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

case class A(b: Int) {
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = {
    println("called")
    obj match {
      case o: A => b == o.b
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}

val set = mutable.Set.empty[A]
val a1 = A(1)
set.add(a1)
println(set.contains(A(1)))
println(set.contains(A(2)))
```

Why the second call of `set.contains` doesn't print out "called"? Can someone explain how set identify two objects being equal?

Comment: A mutable `Set` is backed by a `HashSet` so it first calls the `hashcode` to identify some bucket and then uses `equals` to compare across the elements of the bucket. This why `hashcode` and `equals` MUST always be consistent, if not you open yourself the door to bugs like this one. - BTW, in practice, never override `equals` of a **case class**, if you want custom equiuality use a normal class instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Wonderful! Can you explain what's the original implementation of `hashCode` in Scala and how I could override it if I only want to look at a subset of attributes of a class to determine wether two instances are equal.

Comment: Search for _"Effective Java hashcode and equals"_ - And please, use a normal class unless you want to be heated for future collaborators of your code. Also, I would recommend ticking on a different design, for example moving fields that are not part of equality to a second argument list or having two case classes.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Wonderful! That solves my problems completely. Would you mind writing a brief answer so that I could accept it and close this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentioned in the comments, A mutable `Set` is backed by a `HashSet`. It is well elaborated at [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/2359227)

> Whenever a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode().

This is because `hashCode` is a prior check, which when fails `equals` will definitely fail as well.

From [What code is generated for an equals/hashCode method of a case class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526706/2359227) we can conclude that for case classes `hashCode` and `equals` are overridden for case classes, using `productPrefix` which means the first set of elements in the case class. For example, if we have:

```
case class c(a: A)(b: B)
```

The `hashCode` and `equals` will be calculated only based on `a`. In your case, the `hasCode` method is calculated based on `gender`, which is different for `Person(1)` and `Person(2)`. Therefore there is no need to check `equals`, which suppose to fail as well.

A tip from [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/2359227)

> ### In practice:
>
> If you override one, then you should override the other.
>
> Use the same set of fields that you use to compute equals() to compute hashCode().